# Filepulse Connector error with S3 provider (Source Connector)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to poll csv files from S3 buckets using Filepulse source connector. When the task starts I get the following error.  What additional libraries do I need to add to make this work from S3 bucket ? Config file below.

Where did I go wrong ?

```
Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:208)
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "s3" not installed
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:212)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)
at io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalFileStorage.exists(LocalFileStorage.java:62)
```

Config file :

```
{
  "name": "FilePulseConnector_3",
  "config": {
  "connector.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",
  "filters": "ParseCSVLine, Drop",
  "filters.Drop.if": "{{ equals($value.artist, 'U2') }}",
  "filters.Drop.invert": "true",
  "filters.Drop.type": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.DropFilter",
  "filters.ParseCSVLine.extract.column.name": "headers",
  "filters.ParseCSVLine.trim.column": "true",
  "filters.ParseCSVLine.seperator": ";",
  "filters.ParseCSVLine.type": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.DelimitedRowFilter",
  "fs.cleanup.policy.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LogCleanupPolicy",
  "fs.cleanup.policy.triggered.on":"COMMITTED",
  "fs.listing.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.AmazonS3FileSystemListing",
  "fs.listing.filters":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.RegexFileListFilter",
  "fs.listing.interval.ms": "10000",
  "file.filter.regex.pattern":".*\\.csv$",
  "offset.policy.class":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.offset.DefaultSourceOffsetPolicy",
  "offset.attributes.string": "name",
  "skip.headers": "1",
  "topic": "connect-file-pulse-quickstart-csv",
  "tasks.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalRowFileInputReader",
  "tasks.file.status.storage.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.state.KafkaFileObjectStateBackingStore",
  "tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers": "172.27.157.66:9092",
  "tasks.file.status.storage.topic": "connect-file-pulse-status",
  "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.partitions": 10,
  "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.replication.factor": 1,
  "tasks.max": 1,
  "aws.access.key.id":"<<>>",
  "aws.secret.access.key":"<<>>",
  "aws.s3.bucket.name":"mytestbucketamtrak",
  "aws.s3.region":"us-east-1"
}
}
```

What should I put in the libraries to make this work ? Note : The lenses connector sources from S3 bucket without issues. So its not a credentials issue.

Comment: Suggest you follow - https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse/issues/382

Answer (score 0):

Your JVM is unable to find a `FileSystemProvider` for URIs that have the `s3` scheme (e.g. S3 URIs).

By default the JVM doesn't have a filesystem provider for S3. There is one available from an (awslabs github repo)[https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3]. If the `aws-s3-nio-spi-fors3` jar file is included on the class path of a JVM then your application should be able to read from S3.